# Fill the QLabel/QGraphics widget placed in the grid with the image

Tags: qt, layout

I have placed two QGraphicsView's and one QLabel inside a horizontal layout (QHBoxLayout) with its `layoutStretch` set to `1, 1, 1`. The problem is when I try to load images inside them, the images does not fill the widgets area. Here is the code:

```
QPixmap pix1("image1.jpg");
pix1 = pix1.scaled(ui->label1->size());
ui->label1->setPixmap(pix);

QPixmap pix2("image2.jpg");
pix2 = pix2.scaled(ui->graphicsView1->size());
ui->graphicsView1->scene()->addPixmap(pix2);

QPixmap pix3("image3.jpg");
pix3 = pix3.scaled(ui->graphicsView2->size());
ui->graphicsView2->scene()->addPixmap(pix3);
```

And here is the undesired output:

[image]

I have tried setting `HorizontalPolicy` and `VerticalPolicy` property of widget to `Expanding` and also `Minimum`, but none of them helped either.

Answer (score 0):

Set size policy to `QSizePolicy::Ignored` and scale with `Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding`:

```
ui->label1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
pix1 = pix1.scaled(ui->label1->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
ui->label1->setPixmap(pix);
```

You probably want to scale pixmaps in `resizeEvent()`.

Comment: This improved the result, but the images still don't fill the whole area: http://imgur.com/EyZFCn0

Comment: Didi you implement `resizeEvent()`?

Comment: Yeah that did help. The only problem was that I have to resize the window to get the images fill their container. Using `paintEvent()` instead of `resizeEvent()` solved this too. Is this _the natural_ approach of getting images fill a widget in QT?

Comment: Wow. Now the `paintEvent()` is being called with a high rate, so my solution has very bad performance.

Comment: Well I put the above code in both `showEvent()` and `resizeEvent()` and now it behaves as it should. I guess the widget sizes are not calculated inside the QMainWindow constructor and that's why their images are not scaled to the right size. It would be nice if there was a way to _update_ the widget size in QMainWindow too. Nevertheless, I am going to ask it again: Is this solution a right approach of solving this problem?

Comment: `showEvent()` is not necessary if you set the pixmaps before the window is shown the first time, for example in its constructor. It certainly depends on your implementation. `paintEvent()` is called on many occasions, doing the scaling there is very inefficient indeed.